# How to get the deepest levels of a hierarchical sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I'm using SQLServer 2008.

Say I have a recursive hierarchy table, SalesRegion, whit SalesRegionId and ParentSalesRegionId. What I need is, given a specific SalesRegion (anywhere in the hierarchy), retrieve ALL the records at the BOTTOM level.

I.E.:
SalesRegion, ParentSalesRegionId

1,              null

1-1,            1

1-2,            1

1-1-1,          1-1

1-1-2,          1-1

1-2-1,          1-2

1-2-2,          1-2

1-1-1-1,        1-1-1

1-1-1-2,        1-1-1

1-1-2-1,        1-1-2

1-2-1-1,        1-2-1

(in my table I have sequencial numbers, this dashed numbers are only to be clear)

So, if the user enters 1-1, I need to retrieve al records with SalesRegion 1-1-1-1 or 1-1-1-2 or 1-1-2-1 (and NOT 1-2-2). Similarly, if the user enters 1-1-2-1, I need to retrieve just 1-1-2-1

I have a CTE query that retrieves everything below 1-1, but that includes rows that I don't want:

```
WITH SaleLocale_CTE AS (
    SELECT SL.SaleLocaleId, SL.SaleLocaleName, SL.AccountingLocationID, SL.LocaleTypeId, SL.ParentSaleLocaleId, 1 AS Level /*Added as a workaround*/
      FROM SaleLocale SL
     WHERE SL.Deleted = 0
       AND (@SaleLocaleId IS NULL OR SaleLocaleId = @SaleLocaleId)
     UNION ALL
    SELECT SL.SaleLocaleId, SL.SaleLocaleName, SL.AccountingLocationID, SL.LocaleTypeId, SL.ParentSaleLocaleId, Level + 1 AS Level
      FROM SaleLocale SL
           INNER JOIN SaleLocale_CTE SLCTE ON SLCTE.SaleLocaleId = SL.ParentSaleLocaleId
     WHERE SL.Deleted = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM SaleLocale_CTE
```

Thanks in advance!

Alejandro.

Comment: Is there a maximum depth of 4?  If so, is that also the minimum final depth of any branch?

Comment: @Norla Nope, the maximum number of levels is unknown... but I do need whatever is in the very last level, I'll edit the question to make that clear. Thanks!

Comment: If *you have the luxury* of adjusting the structure you may want to consider the HierarchyID data type. It makes queries like this easy (and often much faster).  Something like `select ... from SL where myHierarchy.IsDecendantOf(@value)` or  myHerarchyID.GetDescendant(@child1, @child2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick way to do this, but I'd rather the answer to be in a single query. So if you can think of one, please share! If I like it better, I'll vote for it as the best answer.

I added a "Level" column in my previous query (I'll edit the question so this answer is clear), and used it to get the last level and then delete the ones I don't need.

```
INSERT INTO @SaleLocales
    SELECT *
      FROM SaleLocale_GetChilds(@SaleLocaleId)

SELECT @LowestLevel = MAX(Level)
  FROM @SaleLocales

DELETE @SaleLocales
 WHERE Level <> @LowestLevel
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off your post:

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM SaleLocale_GetChilds(@SaleLocaleId)
)
SELECT
FROM CTE a
JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(level) AS level
    FROM CTE
) b
    ON a.level = b.level
```

There were a few edits in there.  Kept hitting post...

Comment: It's better than my workaround, but I'll wait to see if someone else gives me an answer that does not require the use of the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
declare @SalesRegion as table ( SalesRegion int, ParentSalesRegionId int )
insert into @SalesRegion ( SalesRegion, ParentSalesRegionId ) values
  ( 1, NULL ), ( 2, 1 ), ( 3, 1 ),
  ( 4, 3 ), ( 5, 3 ),
  ( 6, 5 )

; with CTE as (
  -- Get the root(s).
  select SalesRegion, CAST( SalesRegion as varchar(1024) ) as Path
    from @SalesRegion
    where ParentSalesRegionId is NULL
  union all
  -- Add the children one level at a time.
  select SR.SalesRegion, CAST( CTE.Path + '-' + cast( SR.SalesRegion as varchar(10) ) as varchar(1024) )
    from CTE inner join
      @SalesRegion as SR on SR.ParentSalesRegionId = CTE.SalesRegion      
  )
  select *
    from CTE
    where Path like '1-3%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this on a serious dataset, so I'm not sure how it'll perform, but I believe it solves your problem:

```
WITH SaleLocale_CTE AS (
            SELECT SL.SaleLocaleId, SL.SaleLocaleName, SL.AccountingLocationID, SL.LocaleTypeId, SL.ParentSaleLocaleId, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SaleLocal SL2 WHERE SL2.ParentSaleLocaleId = SL.SaleLocaleID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HasChildren
              FROM SaleLocale SL
             WHERE SL.Deleted = 0
               AND (@SaleLocaleId IS NULL OR SaleLocaleId = @SaleLocaleId)
             UNION ALL
            SELECT SL.SaleLocaleId, SL.SaleLocaleName, SL.AccountingLocationID, SL.LocaleTypeId, SL.ParentSaleLocaleId, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SaleLocal SL2 WHERE SL2.ParentSaleLocaleId = SL.SaleLocaleID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HasChildren
              FROM SaleLocale SL
                   INNER JOIN SaleLocale_CTE SLCTE ON SLCTE.SaleLocaleId = SL.ParentSaleLocaleId
             WHERE SL.Deleted = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM SaleLocale_CTE
WHERE HasChildren = 0
```